# AlertType.CONFIRMATION throws IllegalArgumentException in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, alert, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to add an alert window of confirmation type every time the user tries to delete an item from the ListView. But whenever I do that, once I push the button, an IllegalArgumentException is throwed saying that, duplicate children added. Here's the code:

```
@FXML
private void handleDeleteCaption() {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Delete Caption");
    alert.setHeaderText("Are you sure you want to delete this caption?");
    alert.setContentText("All its contents will be lost. Continue?");

    alert.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.CANCEL);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.YES) {
        captionsList.getItems().remove(selectedCaption);
    }
}
```

It's the same problem when I add the alert of type warning. It only works when I don't specify the type of an alert, namely when I declare it as AlertType.NONE.
What's my missing point here?

Comment: Do you get the IllegalArgumentException on the first line of this method or when you click OK?

Comment: @thurst0n I get it on the line where I call showAndWait() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're probably getting this exception because the button cancel already exists in the Type CONFIRMATION
so you can do

```
alert.getButtonTypes().clear();
```

before

```
alert.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.CANCEL);
```

a better way to do it (as Slaw mentioned in the comments) is by calling setAll without having to clear and re-Add

```
alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.CANCEL)
```